# How to automate a comparison and if no hit, delete a row of information?

Tags: excel, sharepoint, automation, powerapps, power-automate

I have an excel list of employees who have given input via microsoft forms.

I want to check automatically whether those people are still present in the organization.
If so, then the data may remain.
If not, the data must be removed from the excel sheet because it is used in a canvas app.

Also, if possible, I'd like the response to be removed from microsoft forms.

As far as we know there is no Excel list of persons present in the organization. However, all persons are loaded into, for example, Outlook or MS Teams.

What would be a good way to automate the comparison and then update the Excel file?

Answer (score 0):

Form SharePoint side, you go to Microsoft 365 admin center -> Users -> Active users -> Export users to get csv list of present persons in the organization.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could retrieve the responders via the FormAPI. You can retrieve the enabled accounts via [List Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method with a $filter query via the Graph API.

After that you can compare those two arrays within a Filter Array action.

The output of that Filter Array action should be an array with the users which are disabled users who have responded to the form. You can loop through that array and remove the matching items from the Excel.

Below is an example of how to retrieve the users who have been disabled since they have responded to the Microsoft Forms form.

1.Use a Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action with a GET request to the forms.office.com

[image]

2.Use a Select action to get a clean array with only the responder mail addresses

a. Use the expression below in the From Field

```
outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request_to_SharePoint')?['body']['value']
```

b. Switch Map field to text mode (with icon on the right side) and add the expression below

```
item()['responder']
```

[image]

3.Use a Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action with a GET request to the forms.office.com

[image]

4.Use a Select action to get a clean array with only the users which have an enabled account in the tenant

a. Use the expression below in the From Field

```
outputs('Send_an_HTTP_request')?['body']['value']
```

b. Switch Map field to text mode (with icon on the right side) and add the expression below

```
item()['mail']
```

[image]

5.Compare the two arrays in a Filter Array

a. Use the Select - Forms action Output in the From Field

b. Use the following expression (in advanced mode) in the Criteria field

```
@not(contains(body('Select_-_AccountEnabled_Users'), item()))
```

[image]

Comment: How do I setup the variables in the URI?

Comment: Step 5b gives an error: Correct to include a valid reference to 'Select_-_AccountEnabled_Users' for the input parameter(s) of action 'Filter_array'.

Comment: I have renamed the second Select action to 'Select - AccountEnabled Users'. Please rename it to the same name, otherwise it cannot find that action and the reference will be invalid.

Comment: The tenantid is a environment variable. The red id is coming from the Get My Profile action. But it is just the id of the user who created the Forms form. The FormId is the id of the form. All these variables can be either replaced by values or you can create/replace them with three Initialize variable actions (of type string)